# Vaadin CRUD + Microstream: edit not working

Tags: vaadin, microstream

I start using microstream as persistence storage for my Vaadin 24.3.5 SpringBoot 3.2.2 app.
I have a CRUD with some rows using a `ListDataProvider`.
After edit a certain row item (a DTO) by clicking the edit column button and using the CRUD editor, the modified row item / dto is shown properly. The grid row contains the new/updated values.

After clicking the edit column button immediately again for the same row, the CRUD editor remains empty, no item / dto can the modified. After reload the whole page or edit another row, the edit is possible again.

I've tried also a `CallbackDataProvider` with an explicitly set identifierGetter ... same result.

The DTO is a simple `customer` with 4 string attributes, `equals()` and `hashCode()` are implemented manually (no Lombok) appropriately.

What I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Please provide
a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Here is the MRE: https://gist.github.com/to-do42/50f4af64f00bb2d74c50da1be075482b

Comment: First, create new a new item, then edit this item, all textfields of the CRUD editor are filled properly. Save your modifications, the grid update immediately and shows the new values. Edit this item again .... but now all editor fields are empty.